# Fedex checksum algorithm for tracking numbers?

Tags: java, fedex

How do I validate potential Fedex tracking numbers, without hitting a web service?  I've heard Fedex employs a modified version of the Luhn algorithm.

Answer (score 4):

Check the [google answer](http://answers.google.com/answers/threadview/id/207899.html). There are different algorithm for [ground](http://fedex.com/us/solutions/ppe/FedEx_Ground_Label_Layout_Specification.pdf) and express.

Comment: this shows some changes to tracking numbers for 2013 (and corresponding barcodes) that may be useful depending upon what you're doing : http://fedex.p.delivery.net/m/p/fdx/bcc/home.asp